# Gmail Api problems

Tags: gmail-api

We are currently trying to create a tool in Google Apps Script using OAuth2 for Authentication. The script is supposed to use the GMail api to carry out some tasks such as moving labels from one account to another.
Documentation we have used says we need to create a service account with domain wide authority and create necessary components to allow it to work (i.e client_id and so on.. )

We are getting the error below is anyone able to help?

Code:

```
function getGmailService() {
return OAuth2.createService('GmailMigration:' + user_email)
  // Set the endpoint URL.
  .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(CREDENTIALS.auth_uri)

  // Set the private key and issuer.
  .setPrivateKey(CREDENTIALS.private_key)
  .setIssuer(CREDENTIALS.client_email)

  // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
  // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
  // delegation:
  // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
  .setSubject(CLIENT_EMAIL)

  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

  // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
  // setup of domain-wide delegation.
  .setScope('https://mail.google.com https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata');
```

}

```
function reset() {
getGmailService().reset();
```

}

```
function run() {
var service = getGmailService();
if (service.hasAccess()) {
console.log({Service: service})
var url = 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{user_id}/labels/{message/label_id}?key='+CREDENTIALS.api_key;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
  },
  muteHttpExceptions: true
});
var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));} else {
Logger.log(service.getLastError());
```

}
}

Error:

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Precondition check failed.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Precondition check failed.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "failedPrecondition"
}
],
"status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
}

Thanks

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, you are using this as part of a Workspace domain, correct? Can you confirm the value of `CLIENT_EMAIL` in your script? This needs to be the email of the account that is being impersonated. It seems you have another value for that `user_email` - can you confirm the values you are passing in?

Comment: Workspace domain - yes for certain

Client email -> email of the service account we are trying to impersonate

User email -> email of user we wanna perform mail operations on

Comment: Take a look at your scopes, you have got lots of scopes, try it with just `https://mail.google.com/`. Are these scopes granted in both GCP **and** the admin console? Also does your manifest have this scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`?

Comment: Thank you I made the changes you requested and also another change, we changed the email in the setSubject function to the email of the user we want to perform operations on.
the weird thing is we ran this same variation of the code and we had the same errors. Quite confusing why we must have gotten them.
And the manifest did have the scope you suggested

Comment: so it works now?

Comment: Yes it does thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it :)